# How can I convert a JSONObject to a gson.JsonObject?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I have a `org.json.JSONObject` object.

What's the easiest way to create a `gson.JsonObject` object from it?

Thanks

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The easiest way is to serialize your JSONObject to a json string using toString(), then parsing that json string into a JsonObject:

```
    org.json.JSONObject object = <your defined object>;
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject gsonObject = (JsonObject)jsonParser.parse(object.toString());
```

Note that serializing and deserializing an object can be an expensive operation. If you have to do this a lot in your code (inside loops), it can affect your performance.

Comment: is there a way to do the vice versa?

Comment: jsonParser.parse(object.toString()) is returning JsonElement object. I'm not able to cast it to org.json.JSONObject. I'm trying to convert from gson.JsonObject to org.json.JSONObject.

Comment: @Marcelo Filho How about `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonObject.toString());`

Answer (score 0):

in Kotlin use this extension:

```
fun JSONObject.toGsonJsonObject():JsonObject{
    return JsonParser().parse(this.toString()) as JsonObject
}
```